# get next and previous group of cycle items from an array in query

Tags: jquery, arrays

how to get group of items from an array using next and previous in a particular time interval
as below

```
var s=["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","zero"];
```

after 10 seconds

```
var s1=["one","two","three"]
```

and keep updating

```
s1=["four","five","six"]
...
s1=["ten","zero","one"]
```

please suggest to achieve the above functionality.

Comment: Use a counter and slice. Did you try it before asking ?

Comment: this looks like an attempt to create a carousel.. Why not use one that already exists?

Comment: I agree looks like a carousel or slider.  Are you trying to rotate splash images, or banners?  If this is the case there are some great packages that handle all this.  flexslider and nivo come to mind.